# Cannot implement Android Splash Screen on Nx Monorepo

Tags: android, react-native, monorepo, nrwl-nx

I am trying to implement a splash screen following [Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/launch/splash-screen) and [this tutorial](https://www.kodeco.com/32555180-splash-screen-tutorial-for-android). Both mention to modify the `onCreate` method on the `MainActivity.java` file, however `nx` generates a couple of android java files (`MainActivity.java` and `MainApplication.java`), being the onCreate method on the latest, `MainApplication.java`, instead of in `MainActivity.java`, as suggest on above documentation.

I have been trying to modify those files to add the splash screen without success.

You can generate those files by running `npx create-nx-workspace happynrwl --preset=react-native --appName=mobile`

Find below the original `MainApplication.java` generated by `nx`

```
package com.mobile;

import android.app.Application;
import com.facebook.react.PackageList;
import com.facebook.react.ReactApplication;
import com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost;
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.react.defaults.DefaultNewArchitectureEntryPoint;
import com.facebook.react.defaults.DefaultReactNativeHost;
import com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader;
import java.util.List;

public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {

  private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost =
      new DefaultReactNativeHost(this) {
        @Override
        public boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
          return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
        }

        @Override
        protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
          @SuppressWarnings("UnnecessaryLocalVariable")
          List<ReactPackage> packages = new PackageList(this).getPackages();
          // Packages that cannot be autolinked yet can be added manually here, for example:
          // packages.add(new MyReactNativePackage());
          return packages;
        }

        @Override
        protected String getJSMainModuleName() {
          return "src/main.tsx";
        }

        @Override
        protected boolean isNewArchEnabled() {
          return BuildConfig.IS_NEW_ARCHITECTURE_ENABLED;
        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean isHermesEnabled() {
          return BuildConfig.IS_HERMES_ENABLED;
        }
      };

  @Override
  public ReactNativeHost getReactNativeHost() {
    return mReactNativeHost;
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    SoLoader.init(this, /* native exopackage */ false);
    if (BuildConfig.IS_NEW_ARCHITECTURE_ENABLED) {
      // If you opted-in for the New Architecture, we load the native entry point for this app.
      DefaultNewArchitectureEntryPoint.load();
    }
    ReactNativeFlipper.initializeFlipper(this, getReactNativeHost().getReactInstanceManager());
  }
}
```

and `MainActivity.java`:

```
package com.mobile;

import com.facebook.react.ReactActivity;
import com.facebook.react.ReactActivityDelegate;
import com.facebook.react.defaults.DefaultNewArchitectureEntryPoint;
import com.facebook.react.defaults.DefaultReactActivityDelegate;

public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {

  /**
   * Returns the name of the main component registered from JavaScript. This is used to schedule
   * rendering of the component.
   */
  @Override
  protected String getMainComponentName() {
    return "Mobile";
  }

  /**
   * Returns the instance of the {@link ReactActivityDelegate}. Here we use a util class {@link
   * DefaultReactActivityDelegate} which allows you to easily enable Fabric and Concurrent React
   * (aka React 18) with two boolean flags.
   */
  @Override
  protected ReactActivityDelegate createReactActivityDelegate() {
    return new DefaultReactActivityDelegate(
        this,
        getMainComponentName(),
        // If you opted-in for the New Architecture, we enable the Fabric Renderer.
        DefaultNewArchitectureEntryPoint.getFabricEnabled(), // fabricEnabled
        // If you opted-in for the New Architecture, we enable Concurrent React (i.e. React 18).
        DefaultNewArchitectureEntryPoint.getConcurrentReactEnabled() // concurrentRootEnabled
        );
  }
}
```

Do you know what could be wrong and how to modify those file to add the splash screen?

I have tried adding the `androidx.core.splashscreen.SplashScreen.installSplashScreen` to the `onCreate`, but haven't succeed.